# codeigniter filter database

Tags: codeigniter, filter, model, conditional-statements

i have a few checkboxes that filter my elements from a database but i don't know how to apply a filter like price with a min value and a max value, since from my view i can pass to the controller only one value of my inputs
For example: i want to apply a price filter between 1000 and 1500 to an element
**view:**

```
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="1000">  <1.000</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="1500"><a href="#">1.000 - 1.500</a></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="2000"><a href="#">1.500 - 2.000</a></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="3000"><a href="#">2.000 - 3.000</a></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="4000"><a href="#">3.000 - 4.000</a></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="5000"><a href="#">4.000 - 5.000</a></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="5000"><a href="#">  >5.000</a></li>
```

**controller:**

```
public function laptops()
{

    $filter = $this->input->post();



    $data['laptops_toate'] = $this->emag_model->laptops_toate_grid($filter);


    $this->load->view('emag/laptops',$data);
```

**model:**

```
    public function laptops_toate_grid($filter = null){
    $this->db->select('*')
             ->from('laptop_notebook')
            ->join('brands','brands.id_brands = laptop_notebook.brand');


    if($filter['price']){
        $this->db->where('price <', $filter['price']);
    }


    $query = $this->db->get()->result();



    return $query;

}
```

Comment: Do you want to be able to select multiple price ranges at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For just an idea of how you could do it.

The view file:

```
<li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="<1000">  <1.000</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="1000-1500"><a href="#">1.000 - 1.500</a></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="1500-2000"><a href="#">1.500 - 2.000</a></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="2000-3000"><a href="#">2.000 - 3.000</a></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="3000-4000"><a href="#">3.000 - 4.000</a></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="4000-5000"><a href="#">4.000 - 5.000</a></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value=">5000"><a href="#">  >5.000</a></li>
```

The controller remains the same.
The model becomes:

```
public function laptops_toate_grid($filter = null){
    $this->db->select('*')
             ->from('laptop_notebook')
            ->join('brands','brands.id_brands = laptop_notebook.brand');

    if (isset($filter['price'])) { // make sure there is price key
        $filters = array(); // this is where we store the filters
        foreach ($filter['price'] as $price) { // iterate through prices
            if ($filter['price'][0] == '<') { // is less
                $filters[] = 'price < ' . (int)substr($price, 1);
            }
            elseif ($filter['price'][0] == '>') { // is more
                $filters[] = 'price > ' . (int)substr($price, 1);
            }
            else { // is between
                $expl = explode('-', $price);
                $filters[] = 'price BETWEEN ' . (int)$expl[0] . ' AND ' . (int)$expl[1];
            }
        }
        if ($filters) { // if there are filters, create the query
            $query = implode(' OR ', $filters);
            $query = '('. $query . ')';
            $this->db->where($query, false); // false makes sure the query is not escaped
        }
    }

    $query = $this->db->get()->result();

    return $query;
}
```

**Note: this is just a working idea, I haven't been tested the code.**